# Confused about htonl output

Tags: c, binary, endianness

I have simple question. This code:

```
   int t = 1;

   int y = htonl(t);
   printf("Y = %d, sizeof(int)=%d", y, sizeof(int));
```

prints

```
Y = 16777216, sizeof(int)=4
```

On a little endian machine (it is online compiler actually).

I was expecting `y` to be number (in binary): 1000....000 (0 - 31 times).

But 16777216 has only roughly 25 zeros next to 1 (in binary).

What did I miss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int t = 1;
```

In memory (for 4 byte systems) is presented in this way

```
 ---------------
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
 ---------------
  ^            ^
  | byte       | = 0x1 = 00000001 in binary
```

The binary format is

```
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001
```

`htonl()` allow to reverse the bytes if your system is a little endian system

so `htonl(t)` will return:

```
 ---------------
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
 ---------------
  ^
  | = 0x1 = 00000001 in binary
```

so the whole `htonl(t)` in binary is

```
00000001 00000000 00000000 00000000
```

equal to `16777216` in decimal

Comment: Yes, I caught it up recently. That's why the 24-0s in the number: 16777216

Answer (score 1):

It did exactly what you ask it to.

Your output in hex is `01 00 00 00`. `htonl` on little endian swaps **bytes** around, not bits.

```
16777216 = 0x01000000
```